Please help me to identify SMD component with W3 label

Please help me to find this component. It is from A/C module of my car.

It's a ROHM FMW3 dual 2SC3906K NPN transistor.

I can't find a picture of the FMW3, but here is one of the 2SC3906K made by ROHM, to show that this matches their marking style:

(Source: lcsc.com)
